# How can i set same int value to an array of ints

Tags: c++, memset

I have a variable:

```
unsigned int* data = (unsigned int*)malloc(height * width)
```

I want to set same int to all array values.
I can't use memset because it works with bytes.

How can i do that?

Comment: C or C++? Pick one.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `malloc(height * width * sizeof(unsigned int))`?

Comment: Shouldn't your assignment be:

`unsigned int* data = (unsigned int*)malloc(height * width * sizeof(unsigned int))`

Comment: c++ and yes, i renamed the parameters userd and forgot that my width is actually width * sizeof(..)

Comment: If your code fragment is in C, please [don't cast the result of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: @Martinho: I wanted the OP to pick one, not you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using C++:

```
std::vector<unsigned int> data(height * width, value);
```

If you need to pass the data to some legacy C function that expects a pointer, you can use `&data[0]` or `&data.front()` to get a pointer to the contiguous data in a well-defined manner.

If you absolutely insist on using pointers throughout (but you have *no* technical reason to do this, and I wouldn’t accept it in code review!), you can use `std::fill` to fill the range:

```
unsigned int* data = new int[height * width];
std::fill(data, data + height * width, value);
```

Comment: Can it work with pointers? I need data to be of type unsigned int* and i don't want to allocate again in this case. Meaning, i already have allocated array, i just need to fill it with same value

Comment: @Erik, yes you can use `pointer` with `vector` - as here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7e4tx21z.aspx

Comment: @Erik Sapir: If you can let `vector<>` handle the memory allocation for you, just return `&data[0]`. It's well-specified, and unless the vector changes size, it's guaranteed to work.

Comment: std:fill is exactly what i wanted!

Comment: OK edit - it works but it is still a bit slow (compared to memset).

Comment: @Erik `std::fill` internally uses `memset` where possible (i.e. for `char` types). For other scalar types (e.g. `int`) it uses SIMD instructions where available. In short, it uses the fastest possible solution in all cases (at least on modern compilers). There is nothing you can do to make it faster if you already have optimizations enabled.

Comment: @thkala How do you get that weird idea? Why should C library code be more heavily optimised than C++ library code? Anyway, it’s just wrong, see my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your array memory dimension is invariant:

```
#include <vector>

unsigned int literal(500);
std::vector<unsigned int> vec(height * width, literal);
vector<unsigned int>::pointer data = &vec[0];
```

[Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html) might be of interest, since you appear to be indexing points in a space here (dimension of your 1D array comes from height and width).

Comment: vec will be released when function ends, no?

Comment: @Erik - yes, RAII (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) means memory will be released when `vec` goes out of scope.  @Kerrek - point taken, hence the proviso about invariance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are confident that you want an array, do it the C++ way, and don't listen to anyone who says "malloc", "for" or "free candy":

```
#include <algorithm>

const size_t arsize = height * width;
unsigned int * data = new unsigned int[arsize];
std::fill(data, data + arsize, value);

/* dum-dee-dum */

delete[] data; // all good now (hope we didn't throw an exception before here!)
```

If you don't know for sure that you need an array, use a vector like [Konrad says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613372/how-can-i-set-same-int-value-to-an-array-of-ints/6613391#6613391).

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to use a for loop!

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < height * width; i++)
  data[i] = value;
```

Comment: Only in the nonplussed language.

Comment: This is wrong 'height*width' is not necessarily the number of items in the array.

Comment: You're right -- my answer assumes they're single bytes. I was trying to keep the code sample short. If they're not single bytes (which I don't think they are because the questions specifically states they aren't), then isn't the malloc() call incorrect?

Comment: You don't have to use a for loop when you can use `std::fill()`.

Comment: It wasn't initially clear whether he wanted C or C++. And judging by his use of malloc(), I (incorrectly, it would appear!) chose C!

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged this a both C and C++. They are not the same language.

In C, you probably want a code fragment like:

```
// WARNING: UNTESTED
unsigned int* data = malloc(height * width * sizeof (unisgned int));
int i;
for(i = 0; i < height*width; i++)
    data[i] = 1941;
```